# How to access a internal div's ID (auto-incremented) by an external DIV id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

guys!

I got the following code:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++) {
?>

<!--EXTERNAL DIV-->
<div class = "square" onClick = "paint(this.id); doSomethingElse(this.id)"<br> id = "<?php echo "$i" ?>"> 


(...)
<!--Internal DIV-->
<div id = "test<?php echo "$i";?>">
</div>
</div>
```

What I want is: I need to call the 'doSomethingElse' function in the External DIV (because it's a square that will be clicked), but it will show (display: visible) the Internal DIV, so I need to access the internal div's ID from the external div's ID using jQuery or javascript. 

I know it's a little confusing, but I think that's the way I can get what I want.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start, get rid of the break tag in your div. and your id's need to begin with a letter. and your echo statements need a semi-colon:

```
<div class="square" onClick="paint("#a<?php echo "$i"; ?>"); doSomethingElse("#a<?php echo "$i"; ?>")" id = "a<?php echo "$i"; ?>">
```